# Как быстро создать простую БД вакансий?

Tags: база-данных, access

Вопрос, мне нужно сделать БД таблицу с вакансиями и указать в них буквально самое основное: название, расположение, ЗП и т.д. с хх ру. Можно ли автоматизировать этот процесс, чтобы как по шаблону вбить информацию?
Это как бы не моя сфера, я в БД плохо разбираюсь, но по учебе срочно надо, поэтому если кто знает, как можно упростить процесс, буду благодарен.